# Iterate over double nested array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document:

```
{
  "_ID": "234",
  "sub": {
    "abcId": "123",
    "subElems": [
      {
        "abcId": "345",
        "subElems": [
          {
            "abcId": "676",
            "subElems": [
              {
                "abcId": "567"
              },
              {
                "abcId": "567b",
                "crit1": false,
                "crit2": "someId",
                "crit3": "2013-07-30T22:00:00.000+0000",
                "crit4": "ABC"
              },
              {
                "abcId": "567c",
                "crit1": true,
                "crit3": "2013-07-30T22:00:00.000+0000",
                "crit4": "ABC"
              },
              {
                "abcId": "567d",
                "crit1": true,
                "crit3": "2018-11-30T22:00:00.000+0000",
                "crit4": "ABC"
              }
            ]
          },
                    {
            "abcId": "678",
            "subElems": [
              {
                "abcId": "568"
              },
              {
                "abcId": "568b",
                "crit1": false,
                "crit2": "someId",
                "crit3": "2013-07-30T22:00:00.000+0000",
                "crit4": "ABC"
              },
              {
                "abcId": "568c",
                "crit1": true,
                "crit3": "2013-07-30T22:00:00.000+0000",
                "crit4": "ABC"
              },
              {
                "abcId": "568d",
                "crit1": true,
                "crit3": "2018-11-30T22:00:00.000+0000",
                "crit4": "ABC"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to iterate over all `sub.subElems.0.subElems` (in this case the nested documents with `abcId` 676 and 678)

Each of those 2 again have an array of objects called `subElems`.

I need to find all ojects in this `subElems` array that match the following criteria (AND, not OR):

```
crit1 = true
crit4 = ABC
crit2 = null
crit3 = more than a year ago
```

Given the collectin above, I need:

`567c` and `568c`

I have a tried various aggregations.

I thought I could do something like `unwind sub.subElems.0.subElems` and then access its `subElems` array and iterate over that.

What I don't know how to do is select a nested aray of objects (whose path I know) but then iterate over the elements in this array and again iterate over an array in those objects.

Thanks for help and tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

Basically you need to use [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) with each array and [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) with the last one.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "sub.subElems": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$sub.subElems",
        "as": "s1",
        "in": {
          "abcId": "$$s1.abcId",
          "subElems": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$$s1.subElems",
              "as": "s2",
              "in": {
                "abcId": "$$s2.abcId",
                "subElems": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$$s2.subElems",
                    "as": "s3",
                    "cond": {
                      "$and": [
                        { "$eq": ["$$s3.crit1", true] },
                        { "$eq": ["$$s3.crit4", "ABC"] },
                        { "$eq": ["$$s3.crit2", undefined] },
                        { "$lt": ["$$s3.crit3", "2018-11-30T22:00:00.000+0000"] }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! How do I change this so that I get the entire document back?

Comment: And why excactly did you put  "abcId": "$$s1.abcId" ? I removed that and i still seems to work.

Comment: Yes It will work but your `abcId` key will be vanished from the nested arrays and You will only get the `subElems` which we have defined inside the `in` expression of `$map` function